# Convert list of tuples with duplicates to tuple with nested tuple

Tags: scala

I am looking for a nice way to convert a list of tuples such as

```
List((a,b,c,d,e,f),(a,b,c,g,h,i))
```

to something like

```
(a,b,c,List((d,e,f),(g,h,i)))
```

The list can be very large, up to 1000 tuples and the tuples have 20 fields with data types string and integers.

So far, I have figured out the following :

```
  val l = List(("a","b","c","d","e","f"),("a","b","c","g","h","i"))
    val l2=   l.groupBy(x =>(x._1, x._2, x._3))   
//Map((a,b,c) -> List((a,b,c,d,e,f), (a,b,c,g,h,i))) 
    val l3 = l2.map{case (k,v) =>(k._1, k._2, v.map{y =>(y._4,y._5)})}
//List((a,b,List((c,d,e), (c,g,h))))
```

But it is ugly and looks like won't work well for the large list

Comment: List((a,b,c,d,e,f),(a,b,c,d,h,i)) ~~> (a,b,c,d,List((e,f),(h,i))) ?

Comment: Is that a complete example?Or can there be more tuples in your list?

Comment: There are more tuples , as well as the tuples are also large with several duplicate and several unique fields. But they all follow the same pattern.

Comment: I don't really see a problem here, except the type of `l3` is `List[(A, B, List[X])]` whereas initially you specify the type of your desired output to be `(A, B, C, List[X])`. You probably want to have `k._3` included in `l2.map`? Also, `List` seems to be the type you want, so you should update the initial specification, but I can only guess. Regarding your performance considerations: Note that traversing the list twice does not add in asymptotic complexity. Furthermore, `l2` is smaller in size than `l` proportional to the size of `v`, so the complexity should not be quadratic, right?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with tuples is not trivial. I suggest looking at `HList` implementations.

Assuming all items are of the same type you can define your input as:

```
val input: List[Set[Symbol]] = List(
    Set('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f),
    Set('a, 'b, 'c, 'g, 'h, 'i)
)
```

And then compute your result using [Set's intersection & difference](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Set):

```
val output: (Set[Symbol], List[Set[Symbol]]) = {
    val intersection = input.reduce(_ & _)
    val differences = input.map(_ &~ intersection)
    (intersection, differences)
}
```

The result would be:

```
(Set('a, 'b, 'c), List(Set('e, 'f, 'd), Set('i, 'g, 'h)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the tuples have values with different types, actually two : string and integers.  So, we can not use Set

Comment: OK. Please edit your question to add these details. It's quite vague at this point. You should also mention if you always expect 6-tuples. And whether or not types are in fixed positions.

Answer (score 0):

Using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), its one line solution

```
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._
val l = List(("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), ("a", "b", "c", "g", "h", "i"))
l(0).take(3) :+ l.map(_.drop(3))
//res0: (String, String, String, List[(String, String, String)]) =
(a,b,c,List((d,e,f), (g,h,i)))
```